# How can I use the module features in c++20

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

When i learning the book: "Beginning C++20: From Novice to Professinal, Six Edtion (Apress)".

Here is an example:

```cpp
import <compare>;   // Required when using operator <=> .
import <format>;
import <iostream>;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Please enter a number:";
    int value;
    std::cin >> value;

    std::strong_ordering ordering{value <=> 0};

    std::cout << std::format("Value < 0: {}\n", ordering == std::strong_ordering::less);
    std::cout << std::format("Value > 0: {}\n", ordering == std::strong_ordering::greater);
    std::cout << std::format("Value = 0: {}\n", ordering == std::strong_ordering::equal);
}
```

I installed the MinGW-W64 compiler on Windows, and in windows I simply put the "C:\mingw64\bin" directory into the PATH of the windows environment variable.

When i use 'import' keyword, the complier return error with message:

```
error: failed to read compiled module: No such file or directory
```

I think the windows environment does not meet the compilation conditions, (I may install the compiler in the wrong way).

But i turn to linux, error still.

---

My quessions here:

1. Is my compiler installed correctly?
2. What should i do (to pass complie)?
3. There is no "#include" in book's example, Is using 'import' instead of '#include' recommended by modern c++?

So i turn to linux, (using WSL openSUSE-Tumbleweed)

Here is the VSCode connected to wsl.

[vscode on openSUSE-Tumbleweed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40Vch.png)

I try to complie, but error still.

```
$$$ g++ -std=c++20  -fmodules-ts import-module.cpp -o import-module
In module imported at import-module.cpp:1:1:
/usr/include/c++/13/compare: error: failed to read compiled module: No such file or directory
/usr/include/c++/13/compare: note: compiled module file is ‘gcm.cache/./usr/include/c++/13/compare.gcm’
/usr/include/c++/13/compare: note: imports must be built before being imported
/usr/include/c++/13/compare: fatal error: returning to the gate for a mechanical issue
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: I see the error, and I know that the compiler must be missing something that prevents me from using module.

I asked chatgpt and the answer means that the base module should be included by the compiler itself.

Comment: FWIW: The only compiler to fully support modules currently is MSVC, so you should really be using that on Windows instead of MinGW

Comment: Maybe your compiler isn't compliant yet. According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20, GCC (which mingw is based on) only partially implements the feature in version 11.

Comment: And GCC in particular does not yet support importing standard library headers as modules (without some extra, potentially error-prone, building steps): https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Modules.html

Comment: I checked the website [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20), I downloaded the latest version 13.2.0 in windows installation mode at this site https://www.mingw-w64.org/downloads/#mingw-builds and final redirect to https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds-binaries/releases

It is much newer than the website shows need  version 11 to support c++20.

I don't think it's due to the version, it's possible that the binary package in the github release may not have been precompiled?

Comment: @UnholySheep MSVC has full support of modules in theory, but my trials to use them have been failing for more than a year now. I have experienced several compiler *internal errors*, which is a nice way to say that the compiler crashed. But I agree that our C++ code base is quite complex, the crashes happen in some uses of variadic templates.

Comment: @aquawius C++ standards are large enough that each compilers support pieces of them.  A compiler can compile "in C++20 mode" but not support all C++20 features; "in C++20 mode" just means to turn on support for whatever C++20 features it supports.  So again, MinGW does not have modules support.  Even MSDEV last I checked didn't have great modules support, and it was ahead of clang/gcc.

Comment: This is confusing to people who use other languages.  C++ gets *designed by a committee* then compilers *support what the committee designs*.  So the standard is written without compilers supporting it.  Most languages have 1 compiler, and the standard is "whatever the compiler does", so a new language version doesn't exist before the compiler does.